# Excel layout - How to lock layout when hiding rows

Tags: excel, layout, rows

I have a problem, with the layout in my Excel.

I would like to lock the layout, so if i hide a row on side 1, i dont want to have any rows from side 2 to jump into side 1. I want the same layout on the side just with the rows hided that i want.

If i then unhide the cells again they shall fit into the layout as before they were hidden.

Anyone who can help?

Comment: I don't understand. What will be taking up that space? Do you have a screenshot of the input data?

Answer (score 0):

If rows are hidden, they are just that - *hidden*. There's no way to have a hidden row still take up the space that it would take up if it were unhidden.

However, I think I have a way to solve your problem.

You can use conditional formatting on the rows you want to hide, and you can just conditionally format the background color and font color of the rows as the same color (e.g. gray) so that whenever the conditional formatting rule is applied, the desired rows just turn grey, effectively hiding the content the rows but not changing the layout of the sheet.